# Wrap HTML Buttons in a drop-down list

Tags: html

is there a way of wrapping HTML Buttons so that they show in a drop-down list?

I have the following two buttons:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-
target='#authorize'>Show Demo Card Details</button>     
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' 
data-target='#test'>Show Demo Card Details</button>
```

And I would like them to be accessible from a drop-down list, is this possible with html?

Comment: Not with pure html. You'd have to make your own dropdown with JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the markup, I assume you're using Bootstrap. You can't do it with the `<select>` element using plain HTML. If you are using the rest of the Bootstrap features, then you can make use of Bootstrap's dropdown and do something like the one below. Note that you might need to do `event.preventDefault()` for the `<a>` elements inside `li` and you might need to do some more CSS to make it work like you want it to.

You don't really require a `<button>` to trigger a modal by the way. For example, changing the last item in the below dropdown to something like this will also work:

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">JavaScript</a></li>
```

```css
.dropdown li span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<! -- Bootstrap Dropdown -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Try this </span>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#authorize'>Show Demo Card Details</button>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span href="#">Try another?</span>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Show Demo Card Details</button>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="bg-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<!-- Example modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This is what I have done, but I mark your answer as accepted since this is what I had to do anyway. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score -3):

you can simply just add like this in your html

```
<option data-toggle='modal' data-
target='#authorize'>Show Demo #authorize Details</option>
<option data-toggle='modal' 
data-target='#test'>Show Demo #test Details</option>
```

Comment: it's better if you show the code for the entire `select` element... Otherwise, this show two lines of text